# How can I present information on top of a full screened youtube video embedded on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-javascript-api

I am developing a web application where I have a youtube video player embedded in one of my web pages. I am trying to present extra information on top of the playing video (on full screen). By extra information I mean a message with some text or maybe an image.
The code for the embedded player is similar to this:

```
<div id="player" align="center"></div>

  <noscript>This feature requires Javascript, please turn it on</noscript>

  <script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    var uid;
    var firstStatus = 1;
    var firstTimeStamp = 0;
    // Current state of the player
    var state = -1;

    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    var show = getVarsFromUrl()['showId'];
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: show,//'a8u_a9q978M',//'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }
```

I intend to present the extra information on top of a playing video.
I hope I was clear enough. Thanks!

Extra code:
The style (CSS):

```
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  img {
    position:relative;
    left:500px;
    top:500px;
    z-index:5;
  }
  iframe {
    position:absolute;
    left:500px;
    top:500px;
    z-index:-1;
  }
</style>
```

And the image:

```
<img src="smiley.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `?wmode=opaque` to the end of the url to enable the use of `z-index`. Then use `z-index` in your CSS to layer your styles accordingly.

Comment: It does not work. The youtube video on full screen covers whatever image I display even with high z-index value. `img {
        position:absolute;
        left:500px;
        top:500px;
        z-index:5;
      }`

Comment: You'll have to post more code (css/html) for me to help much more.

Comment: I just posted the CSS code and the img. The whole page is quite big, but let me know if you need something else. By the way, thanks for the help!

Comment: The image appears on top of the youtube player, until I enter full screen when the image disappears all together. Somewhere else someone said that when you enter full screen a new flash player window is open, hence its impossible to show anything on top of it. It can not be like that, I am sure there is a way to do it.