# On a web page with an embedded youtube player. How do I show an image above a full screen video?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a web page with an embedded youtube player. I need to show an image  on top of a full screen playing video (flash). I have tried using z-index but it does not seem to go over the full screened player. 
I asked this question in a similar way yesterday ([How can I present information on top of a full screened youtube video embedded on my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623751/how-can-i-present-information-on-top-of-a-full-screened-youtube-video-embedded-o)) but I am trying to be clearer and more specific here. 
The web page uses HTML + Javascript.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add anything ontop of the Fullscreen Flash view (Not that i know of anyway), if you click the expand/fullscreen-view button on the Youtube Player, it opens itself in a brand new Flash Window, thus realy you wouldn't be able to put anything ontop of it i guess.

Comment: Mike. How sure are you about what you are posting? I understand that you should only post a question when you know with certainty what you are talking about. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes i am fairly sure this is correct, he wants to do it with Javascript and HTML - As far as i understand, you will not be able to acheive this when it's fullscreen viewing (IE, no browser windows, no start bar ect).
I'm pretty sure Youtube won't allow custom watermarks over their player either. It would violate a few Terms i think.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using JW Player to play the Youtube video, you can add custom watermark's/logo/image ontop of the player. Although i think for that you have to pay for the "pro" version, more info can be found [Here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player#logo)

Answer (score 0):

The closest way(s) i can think of:

Use a "videobackground"
search Flashden.com or Activeden.com for "youtube video background"
this will play a youtube video as a real background (lowest-z)
so you could even put your whole website on top of it.
It will have fullscreen/fullbrowserframe size...some have overlayed controls also.

http://activeden.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=youtube+video+background

This one seems to have lots of options:

http://activeden.net/item/youtube-flash-video-background/158732?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=dSKY

With some additional code you could open such page with youtube-background
from a link on your normal videoplayer or page.

Or alternatively if you edit your own videos:
you add the image to (in) the video itself.

Or alternatively if you uploaded the video yourself:
Youtube has an option to add an small overlayed text/box
Since a while i see they now allow real pics as ovelays also,
you can set the time it appears and disappers
not shure what the max sizes are...and if its (pic) maybe only for partners.